# Can you use ScrollIntoView() with a PagedCollectionView in a Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagridview, datagrid

Is it possible to scroll to a particular row (by object identity) in a Silverlight [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.95).aspx) that has an [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource(v=VS.95).aspx) which is a [`PagedCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(VS.95).aspx).

I am loading a list of orders that are grouped by day/status etc. I need to be able to scroll to a particular order.

```
 var pcv = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.Orders);
 gridOrders.ItemsSource = pcv;
```

Unfortunately, [`ScrollIntoView(order)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083(VS.95).aspx) doesn't work because of the [`PagedCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(VS.95).aspx).

[An article on DataGrid from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(VS.95).aspx) shows that it is possible to scroll to a group in a [`PagedCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(VS.95).aspx), but that's not really much use.

```
  foreach (CollectionViewGroup group in pcv.Groups)
  {
       dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(group, null);
       dataGrid1.CollapseRowGroup(group, true);
  }
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to scroll items into view when the item source is a [`PagedCollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(VS.95).aspx). I use both the group scrolling method you describe and I scroll the currently selected item into view.  To do this, I have a helper method that uses the dispatcher to invoke the operation as follows:

```
private void ScrollCurrentSelectionIntoView()
{
    this.dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        this.dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(
            this.dataGrid.SelectedItem,
            this.dataGrid.CurrentColumn);
    });
}
```

I used [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259(VS.95).aspx) because otherwise, the call to [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083(VS.95).aspx) would fail when called directly from an event handler (presumably because the [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.95).aspx) hadn't properly updated its state for the event being handled). This approach ensures that the current event handling completes properly before invoking the scroll.