# Silverlight Datagrid Scrolling

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid in Silverlight that uses PageCollectionView but can't get it to scroll vertically after reseting the ItemsSource.

I read the current values of the vertical and horizontal scrollbars, update the itemssource and then reapply the values. It works fine on the horizontal but not the vertical. I can actually see the vertical bar in its new position but the actual table stays at row 1.

I've also tried using ScrollIntoView but no luck.

```
            ScrollBar sbV = (ScrollBar)els.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(ScrollBar)).ToList()[0];
            ScrollBar sbH = (ScrollBar)els.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(ScrollBar)).ToList()[1];
            double vVal = sbV.Value;
            double hVal = sbH.Value;

            dgDevices.ItemsSource = lst;

            dgDevices.UpdateLayout();
            sbH.Value = hVal;
            dgDevices.UpdateLayout();
            sbV.Value = vVal;
```

Comment: Did you try ScrollIntoView with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4088086/2622972

Comment: I did indeed but still no joy. Thanks...

Comment: Why do you need UpdateLayout call? Two, even.